# How to perform action on OK of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, joptionpane

I am working on my first desktop based Java project. I have 2 questions actually

1) How to perform action on OK button of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.I want to navigate to a new Jframe say x.java on clicking ok.

2) I have a table named as user. This table has 8 columns userid (Primary Key), name, password,emailid, dob, mobileno ,city, date. Four column entries has to be fetched from a Jframe x and remaining four from other Jframe y.

I wrote the following code

For Frame X

```
PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement("insert into user  

(userrid,name,password,emailid))values (?,?,?,?) ");

      stm.setString(1,id); // id is a public variable
      stm.setString(2,name);
      stm.setString(3,ps);
      stm.setString(4,email);
     stm.executeUpdate();
```

And for Frame Y. (userid is primary key)

```
public class Y extends javax.swing.JFrame
{  
    X o = new X(); // to access id variable from frame X

} 



PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(" update user set  dob ='? ', mobileno 
='?' ,city='?', date='?'  where userid= 'o.id' ");
```

It keeps throwing exceptions for the above sql query

java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> 1) How to perform action on OK button of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.I want to navigate to a new Jframe say x.java on clicking ok.

```
int input = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Hello World", "The title", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

if(input == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> It keeps throwing exceptions for the above sql query
>
> java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of
>   parameters, which is 0).

That's because you're using `'?'` in Update statement and `'` is no needed. You should  rewrite like this (assuming you're setting parameters properly):

```
PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE user SET dob = ?, mobileno = ?, city = ?, date = ?  where userid= 'o.id' ");
```

Answer (score 0):

The showMessageDialog does not return a value, so any must take place in a different JOptionPane. The one in the above answer is a good example.

Adding to the above answer, if int input is equal to OK_OPTION, you could call dispose() on the current frame (if you are moving from one to the next without keeping the original) and then create a new instance of the desired frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code before closing my java program and it works. On `no_option` the programm still running but you have to set the defaultcloseoperation of your frame on : setDefaultCloseOperation(`JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`);

```
int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure to close this window?", "Really Closing me?",JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
            if (dialogResult==0){
                 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    try{
                    myDBExecuter.closeConnection();
                    myDBExecutero.closeConnection();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,new JTextField(" GoodBye :( "));
                    }
                     System.exit(0);
            }else contentPane.updateUI();//after else can you put what you want als alternative
```